# Permissions for underlying tables while using internal SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server, database-permissions

Normally I used Windows authentication with MSSQL server. There were schemas in databases which correspond to specific Windows logins. These schemas I used for stored procedures, but underlying tables were `dbo` with default permissions.

Now I try to use SQL Server internal authentication and the server writes:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'XXXX', database 'nnnnnn', schema 'dbo'.
```

where XXXX is a table name.

Here is a script to create database:

```
CREATE LOGIN the_user WITH PASSWORD = 'kjzgfkzf'
GO
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [my_database]
GO
USE [my_database]
GO
CREATE USER [the_user] FOR LOGIN [the_user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[lic]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [lic] AUTHORIZATION [the_user]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE App(
    AppId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AppName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_App] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AppId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT App ON
INSERT App (AppId, AppName) VALUES (1, N'Adobe Photoshop 1.0')
INSERT App (AppId, AppName) VALUES (2, N'Microsoft Windows 3.11')
INSERT App (AppId, AppName) VALUES (3, N'ABBYY Fine Reader 8.0')
INSERT App (AppId, AppName) VALUES (4, N'Microsoft Office 2007')
INSERT App (AppId, AppName) VALUES (5, N'ABBYY Lingvo 12')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT App OFF

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [User](
    UserId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [User] ON
INSERT [User] (UserId, [Login], [Password]) VALUES (1, N'asdfff', N'12345')
INSERT [User] (UserId, [Login], [Password]) VALUES (2, N'luke', N'sdjkh')
INSERT [User] (UserId, [Login], [Password]) VALUES (3, N'arny12', N'jfylufyul')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [User] OFF

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE lic.User_Find
    @Login VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT
        UserId
    FROM [User]
    WHERE
        [Login] = @Login
        AND [Password] = @Password
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [License](
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    AppId int NOT NULL,
    Amount int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_License] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [AppId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT License (UserId, AppId, Amount) VALUES (1, 1, 5)
INSERT License (UserId, AppId, Amount) VALUES (1, 2, 2)
INSERT License (UserId, AppId, Amount) VALUES (2, 2, 1)
INSERT License (UserId, AppId, Amount) VALUES (2, 3, 1)
INSERT License (UserId, AppId, Amount) VALUES (2, 5, 3)

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE lic.License_List
    @UserId INT
AS
    SELECT
        a.AppId,
        a.AppName,
        l.Amount
    FROM
        license l
        INNER JOIN app a ON a.AppId = l.AppId
    WHERE
        l.UserId = @UserId
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_License_Amount]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Amount]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_License_App] FOREIGN KEY([AppId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[App] ([AppId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_License_App]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_License_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_License_User]
GO
```

Could you suggest this script change which will make the server using underlying tables without setting explicit permissions on each of them?

Comment: Why you create the login `the_user`?

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan: Because I have to. It is a test example which should run fine on an employer's PC from the very first time.

Comment: Perhaps you must log in by this login before you create your DB objects.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan: This login shouldn't have any DDL permissions.